# Thrift package org.apache.thrift.protocol does not exist

Tags: java, package, thrift

I tried many sample codes online, but I always failed. It always says:

> error: package org.apache.thrift does not exist

I added dependency into POM.xml, and I installed Thrift. But when it finish installing, I saw

> Building Java Library ........ : no

Does it matter?

Anyone can help me? I spent a lot of time to install thrift and solve this problem, I'm so frustrated.

Comment: "*I installed Thrift*" -- what did you install exactly?

Comment: "*Building Java Library ........ : no*" -- it also says at the end of the build "*if you are not satisfied with what you see look into the logfile*"

Comment: @JensG uhh I followed the installation instruction on the official website, and completed all steps lol. And yes, I saw that line, you mean I should check the logfile? But I don't know where it is lol. And I also added " --with-java" in the command, but the results were the same.

Comment: It's one of the *.log files in the root dir of your working copy, where ./configure is located. It's a bit large, since it contains a lot of details, but that should point out why your installed Java is not detected.

Comment: ohh, OK, I'll try lol. Thank you! @JensG